# Almost sure convergence problem involing normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Show that for a sequence of random variables i.i.d following standar normal distribution  $P(\liminf_{n\to\infty} n^{k}|S_{n}|=0)=1$ if $k\leq 1/2$.
I know that the proof involves Kochen-Stone lemma.

Comment: This is an exercise. Please share first what you have tried to do.

Comment: the problem is that i don't know how to start it .The only thing i can see is that 0-1 law applies ,but that doen't seems to help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to show that with for every $\epsilon>0$, with probability one $n^k|S_n| < \epsilon$ **infinitely often**. Can you estimate $P(n^k|S_n| < \epsilon)$ ? Then you just use Borel-Cantelli (second lemma, with independence).

2nd edit : why does a problem about liminf of sequences confusingly turns into a problem of limsup of events ? That's because
$$ \{\liminf X_n = 0\} = \{\forall \epsilon>0, ( X_n<\epsilon \text{ infinitely often})\} = \bigcap_{\epsilon > 0} \limsup_{n\geq 0}\{X_n<\epsilon\} $$

Comment: I will try it .I think though that the probability must be written with the liminf of the event you wrote inside and then take the liminf outside and continue from there.Thanks a lot

Comment: yes i understand that, limsup means i.o and liminf the correction you did.You gave me though a starting point and i appreciate that .I will think to that and hopefully i will come with the proof

Comment: Sorry I was thrown off by your first answer talking about liminfs. The problem *is* about limsups of events and things happening infinitely often. I should not have edited my answer. I will even complete it to clarify the confusing situation of having a liminf (of sequences) in the statement, and a limsup (of events) in the proof.